# Elastic Search Function Score Query For Date Gives Error

Tags: curl, elasticsearch

Mappings

```
[
     "crushlings" => [
       "mappings" => [
         "user_profiles" => [
           "properties" => [
             "about_me" => [
               "type" => "string",
               "analyzer" => "standard",
             ],
             "created_at" => [
               "type" => "string",
             ],
             "dob" => [
               "type" => "date",
               "format" => "yyyy-MM-dd",
             ],
             "first_name" => [
               "type" => "string",
               "analyzer" => "standard",
             ],
             "flagged" => [
               "type" => "integer",
             ],
             "gender" => [
               "type" => "integer",
             ],
             "id" => [
               "type" => "long",
             ],
             "last_name" => [
               "type" => "string",
               "analyzer" => "standard",
             ],
             "location" => [
               "type" => "geo_point",
               "fielddata" => [
                 "format" => "compressed",
                 "precision" => "1km",
               ],
             ],
             "quirky_fact" => [
               "type" => "string",
               "analyzer" => "standard",
             ],
             "updated_at" => [
               "type" => "string",
             ],
             "user_id" => [
               "type" => "long",
             ],
           ],
         ],
       ],
     ],
   ]
```

Query

```
curl -XGET localhost:9200/crushlings/user_profiles/_search?pretty  -d 
'{
  "query": {
    "function_score": {
      "functions": [
        {
          "gauss": {
            "dob": {
              "origin": "2015-08-08",
              "scale": "6y",
              "offset": "24y",
              "decay": 0.33
            }
          }
        }
      ],
      "query": {
        "bool": {
          "must": {
            "term": {
              "gender": "0"
            }
          },
          "must_not": {
            "term": {
              "gender": "0"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}'
```

getting following error

```
nested: ElasticsearchParseException[Failed to parse [6y]]; nested: NumberFormatException[For input string: \"6y\"]; }]",  "status" : 400
```

Indexed Document

```
App\UserProfile {#1418
         id: 1,
         first_name: "First_1",
         last_name: "Last_1",
         gender: 1,
         dob: "1996-12-08",
         about_me: "Beatae harum.",
         quirky_fact: "Non.",
         location: "21.85646, 75.431322",
         user_id: 1,
         flagged: 0,
         created_at: "2015-08-08 14:48:16",
         updated_at: "2015-08-08 14:48:16",
       },
```

- Using elastic search 1.6 on ubuntu 14.02 on Laravel 5+ with elasticquent as a wrapper for elastic search.
- The above also tested on command line to make sure not a framework or wrapper error.

Comment: your query negates itself (must and must not `gender: "0"`) and it also is type mis-matched as a string (`gender: 0 vs "0"`).  I can't see why this would result in your error but I don't see anything else it could be yet.  hope someone comes along with the answer im interested now too.

Comment: For now you can use day notation. So for "1y" , use "365d" and multiply as needed

Comment: Thanks @VineethMohan that works as day only. y does not work.